# Is it possible to configure replication between Mysql 8.0 (Master) and Maria 5.5.68 (Slave)?

Tags: replication, mariadb, mysql-8.0

Currently we have to upgrade 5.5.68-MariaDB to MySQL 8.0.x (Community) which will be a Master server in Replication configuration.

Now my question is, Is it possible to configure replication between Mysql 8.0 (Master) and Maria 5.5.68 (Slave) ?

Is it possible to configure replication between MySQL 8.0 (Master) and Maria 5.5.68 (Slave) ?